# Closed subsets and zero subsets of differentiable functions.[BabyRudin 5.21]

Tags: real-analysis

Two questions I want to ask one about the title the other about the question itself.

### Title

Should I be putting things like [BabyRudin 5.21] in the title. I have read posts about students at universities using this site the cheat on there homework and I want to make sure my posts stay on the ethical side.

### Problem

> Let E be a closed subset of $R^1.$ Is it possible, for each closed set E, to find such an $f$ on $R^1$ which has E as it's zero set and is differentiable on $R^1$.

The question also asks what is the highest differentiable function with E as it's zero set.

[Not the exact phrasing of the question, but all information is there]

### My work

I found that if E is finite then you can find a function $f$ which is |E|th differntiable namely $f(x)=\prod\limits_{a_i\in E}(x-a_i),$ if E is countably infinite but finitely periodic (i.e. if for some finite set $\{a_i \}$ and some real number $r$,  $E=\bigcup\limits_{k\in Z} \{a_i+rk\}$) then there is the infinitely differentiable function $f(x)=\prod\limits_{a\in \{a_i\}}\sin(\frac{2\pi (x-a)}{r})$ and finally if $E=[a,b]$ then you have the function $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
    (x-a)^n, & \text{if } x\leq a\\
    0,              & x\in(a,b)\\
    (x-b)^n, & \text{if } x\geq b
\end{cases}$

which is itself a nth differentiable function.

### My question

Aside from those specific examples, I really can't think of a way to generalize the idea to all closed sets up to a certain carnality. If it cannot be generalized could you point me to a set that doesn't quite have a diferentiable function $f$ associated with it?

Comment: Hint: Every closed set is the complement of an open set, and an open set is a disjoint union of intervals.

Comment: Thank you for the response I will go think about that while I eat, and hopefully come back and answer my own question.

Comment: @Jose27 Do you mean assign to each $(a_i,b_i)$  differentiable function $f$such that $\lim\limits_{x\to a_i}f(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to b_i}f(x)=0?$

Comment: Yes, build on your own examples and see what you can come up with (hint: think of something like $(x-a_i)^n(b_i-x)^n$).